Proof that the expected value of moving from any state to any state is finite in a markov chain
The theorem that I'm trying to prove states that if $\left(X\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an irreducible Markov chain with a finite state space $\left|E\right|<\infty$ then for all $i,j\in E$ we get that $\mathbb{E}_{i}\left[\tau_{j}\right]<\infty$ where $\tau_{j}=\inf\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}|X_{n}=j\right\} $ and $\mathbb{E}_{i}$ means taking the probability distribution with respect to the intial state $i$. I'm trying to prove this theorem differently from what I've seen in class, and I'll really appreciate your thoughts about it.Proof:Since the Markov chain is irreducible, we know that for all $i,j\in E$ there's $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t the probability of getting from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps is positive, we will denote this by $p_{i,j}^n>0$. Furthermore, we will denote $N_{i,j} =\min\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}|p_{i,j}^{n}>0\right\}  \forall i,j \in E$
and then we will define $N:=\underset{i,j\in E}{\max}\left\{ N_{i,j}\right\} $ and $p:=\underset{i,j\in E}{\min}\left\{ p_{i,j}\right\}>0 $
we can observe that for all $i,j\in E$: $\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}\leq N\right)=\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}\left\{ X_{k}=j\right\} \right)\geq p_{i,j}^{N_{i,j}}\geq p>0$ and therefore $\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}>N\right)\leq1-p<1$

Now we define an event $B_{k}=\left(\bigcup_{l=1}^{N}\left\{ X_{Nk+l}=j\right\} \right)^{c}=\left(\bigcap_{l=1}^{N}\left\{ X_{Nk+l}\neq{}j\right\} \right)$ and notice that $\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}>N\right)=\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(B_{0}\right)\leq1-p$
In addition, for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ we get:
$$
\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}>kN\right)=\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\bigcap_{m=0}^{k-1}B_{m}\right)\underset{\left(\ast\right)}{=}\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(B_{m}\right)\leq\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}\left(1-p\right)=\left(1-p\right)^{k}
$$
$\left(\ast\right)$ - The idea here is that we partition the natures into section of length $N$, and $B_{m}$ represent all the paths in the $m$-th section that does not reach state $j$. Let us observe that the event $B_{0}$ is in the section $\left[1,Nk\right]$ meaning that the event is determined by $X_{1},X_{2},\dots,X_{Nk}$ where $X_{0}=i$. The event $B_{1}$ is in $\left[Nk+1,2Nk\right] $ so $B_{1}$is determined by $X_{Nk+1},\dots,X_{2Nk}$. Since the chain is irreducible, we can use the strong Markov property and think about $B_{1}$ as a “new” chain where the initial state is set “deterministically” $\tilde{X}_{0}=X_{Nk}$ and therefore we get the $B_{0}$ and $B_{1}$ are independent. We can use induction to show that $B_{0},\dots,B_{k-1}$ are independent. Let's observe $\mathbb{E}_{i}\left[\tau_{j}\right]$:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{i}\left[\tau_{j}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}>k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=Nk}^{N\left(k+1\right)-1}\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}>Nk\right)\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}N\mathbb{P}_{i}\left(\tau_{j}>Nk\right)\leq N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-p\right)^{k}=N\left(\frac{1-p}{p}\right)<\infty
$$
and therefore $\mathbb{E}_{i}\left[\tau_{j}\right]<\infty$
